# ASP.NET Web API 2 reading values from config file or database or elsewhere

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my asp.net web API 2, I am reading values from web.config from the controller into my DTO as a response to the client. It is working as expected, I wonder if there are any improvements to make it better. Should I read it from a database or elsewhere? So I would be glad if you can share your comments.

Here is the controller related part:

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("reconciliation")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GameReconciliation(ReconciliationDto reconciliationDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

            using var recon = await _gameServices.GameReconciliation(reconciliationDto);

            

            switch (recon.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                    {
                        return InternalServerError();
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    {
                        var responseStream = await recon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        var resultResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReconciliationResponse>(responseStream);

                        //Transform ReconciliationResponse into DTO for returning result
                        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                        {
                            cfg.CreateMap<ReconciliationResponse, ReconciliationResponseDto>().ForMember(x => x.ReconDateTime,
                                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src.ReconciliationResponseDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))));
                        });
                        var iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
                        var resultDto = iMapper.Map<ReconciliationResponse, ReconciliationResponseDto>(resultResponse);
                        //EAN Barcode Added
                        **resultDto.Ean = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["000000001570"];**
                        return Ok(resultDto);
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                    {
                        return Unauthorized();
                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout:
                    {
                        return InternalServerError();
                    }
            }

            recon.Dispose();

            return Ok(recon);
        }
```

Here is web.config related part:

```
 <appSettings>
    <!--TEST EAN-->
    <add key="000000001570" value="9799753293685" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it is impossible for us to answer your question.

- If this is the same value on all environments and it will likely never change, why not hardcode it in the C# code as a `const` in some appropriately named class?
- If it changes per environment: put it in the .config.
- If this is a value that might change regularly and you don't want to do a deploy each time: put it in the DB.

---

WRT your code:

- Keep controllers and the methods therein small. Use something like [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) to move logic to specific classes.
- Don't needlessly abbreviate. Sure, the next maintainer of this code can figure out what `recon` means and/or what it is, but they shouldn't need to spend time on this: your code should make it clear what it is/does.
- Don't use meaningless prefixes. I guess `iMapper` is an `IMapper`, but that doesn't mean you need to call it that. Plus, I assume `CreateMapper` returns an actual `mapper`, not simply an `interface`.
- Why is your mapping logic inside this class, even inside this method? I'd expect that kind of logic to be in a separate class, and that class to be injected. For instance via your API's `Startup` class by [using the `AddAutoMapper` method](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html) (if you're using AutoMapper).
- I'm not a fan of seeing things like `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["000000001570"];` in the middle of code. I usually put all the configuration settings in a specific `static` class (named e.g. "WebApiConfiguration") and all of the settings would be in that class as `public` `static` properties, e.g. `public static string EnvironmentName => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvironmentName"];`. This also allows me to have typed settings if necessary, e.g. `public static bool LogDetails => _lazyLogDetails.Value;` uses `private static readonly Lazy<bool> _lazyLogDetails = new Lazy<bool>(() => ConfigurationHelper.GetBool("LogDetails"));` which itself uses a [method from this class](https://github.com/BJMdotNET/code-samples/blob/master/ConfigurationHelper.cs).